# Storing on the JVM as opposed to the Session

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, httpcontext

I have some meta information, that applies to all users not just the session.  Is there an application context object I can use to store this information?  Would rather not persist it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) for this purpose. There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine. You can use its [setAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method to store your information.
`void setAttribute(java.lang.String name,java.lang.Object object)`
It takes a name value pair. Value(Object) being the info that you want to store.